# ADO.Net FillDatatable giving systemoutofmemoryexception during remoting

Tags: c#, ado.net, remoting

I'm encountering a problem when I use remoting to fill a datatable with > 1000 records.
It keeps giving me a system.outofmemoryexception.

I have tried setting the datatable's remotingformat to Binary but it reverts back to xml after filling the datatable.

Given that the datatable.rows.count is not exactly that huge, and the fact that i'm able to return the results from visualstudios's sql browser, I'm thinking that there's probably a configuratio issue with my remoting setup.

Can anyone suggest where I should start looking and also whether I would still encounter the above mentioned problems if I migrated to wcf

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/95134/why-does-dataset-not-serialize-its-binaryformat-property-ado-net-2-0          This will explain why RemotingFormat changing back to XML.

Comment: http://www.develop-one.net/blog/2008/05/21/WCFSerializationAndRemotingFormat.aspx   This article indicates WCF does not support RemotingFormat property.

Answer (score 0):

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/95134/why-does-dataset-not-serialize-its-binaryformat-property-ado-net-2-0

This will explain why RemotingFormat changing back to XML.

http://www.develop-one.net/blog/2008/05/21/WCFSerializationAndRemotingFormat.aspx

This article indicates WCF does not support RemotingFormat property.